# How to display Timespan in hh:mm:ss format in Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, timespan

I want do dislpay the timestamp obtained from MediaElement.Position in hh:mm:ss format. When  I am using the following code

```
 media.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString()
```

it returns me the time in hh:mm:ss.ffff. How can I convert it to hh:mm:ss format(ie.. truncate the decimal part of seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may to use this extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
        public static string ToHumanString(this TimeSpan time)
        {
            if (time.TotalMinutes < 60)
            {
                return time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            }

            return time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
}
```